# Error on importing excel into sql server through asp.net fileupload

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I am trying to import excel sheet's data into a table in sql server database i am getting an error :  The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object 'Sheet1$'.  Make sure the    object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.

BELOW IS MY CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

public partial class abc2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         String strConnection = "Data Source=DITSEC3;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True";
         //file upload path
         string path = fileuploadExcel.PostedFile.FileName;
         //Create connection string to Excel work book
         string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False";
         //Create Connection to Excel work book
         OleDbConnection excelConnection =new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
         //Create OleDbCommand to fetch data from Excel
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select [ID],[Name],[Designation] from    [Sheet1$]",excelConnection);
         excelConnection.Open();
         OleDbDataReader dReader;
         dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
         //Give your Destination table name
         sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Excel_table";
         sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
         excelConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you open the file and see the sheet name?

Answer (score 0):

I think the excel sheet you are trying to import is having differnt name than $sheet1 so, to get sheet name use follwing code and pass that name of sheet to the sql query to get the data from sheet.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/05c92891-b839-45c8-80df-eb35e2d68258

Comment: I have checked the name of the sheet its "sheet1", i later changed it to "$sheet1" and then "sheet1$" but same error

Comment: you don`t need to changed name of sheet, just use code given in link to get name of sheet. becuase if you put hardcoded value of sheet then, and if it is chnaged sometime so it wont work. so its better to get sheet name dynamicaly than hard coded value.

Comment: Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = null;

string strPath="MENTION PATH OF EXCEL FILE HERE";

theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(strPath, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(1);//Get the reference of second worksheet

string strWorksheetName = worksheet.Name;//Get the name of worksheet.
and use strWorksheetName in select query to get column data

Answer (score 0):

Excel.Application ExcelObj = new Excel.Application();

Excel.Workbook theWorkbook = null;

string strPath="MENTION PATH OF EXCEL FILE HERE"; theWorkbook = ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open(strPath, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);

Excel.Sheets sheets = theWorkbook.Worksheets;

Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)sheets.get_Item(0);//Get the reference of 
second worksheet string strWorksheetName = worksheet.Name;//Get the name of worksheet.

and use strWorksheetName in select query to get column data